# Black color appearing over the button when user clicks on the button

Tags: css

i am using enyo buttons in iphone....the problem is , when i click on button for a                       navigation , black color appears over the button....i dont know whether it is shadow or      border-color or background-color.... i want  to remove this...plz help me....

```
my code goes here

     .onyx-Button2 {
        outline: 0;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1px 1px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 3px;
        /* for IE8 */
        border: 1px solid #777;
        border: 1px solid rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.2);
            /*
        The border and the gradient interact in a strange way that
        causes the bottom-border (top if the gradient is aligned top)
        to be lighter than other borders.
        We can fix it by using the darker bottom border below, but
        then there are a few rogue pixels that end up very dark.
    */ 
        box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
        background: #E1E1E1 url(../../images/gradient.png) repeat-x bottom;
        background-size: contain;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;


}
```

Comment: Can't see any problem http://jsfiddle.net/mpqVG/ what's your css for the hover or active event?

Comment: css for hover and active content is as follows

 

     .onyx-Button2 :hover {
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    .onyx-Button2:active {
     text-decoration: none;
    }                                                                    The Black color appears only in IOS Devices (but not in android) ...plz do help me....

Answer (score 1):

It is possibly down to defaults set within the browser on iOS - I would set all the appropriate properties to cover all bases.

So add

```
background-color:#ffffff; // Change this to your color you want
```

I suspect it is just the way iOS defaults some CSS, it may also have something to do with the manner in which it deals with image's as backgrounds. Unfortunately while iOS goes with most standards, it has odd ways of implementing certain CSS.